# Android imported AAR how to keep changes in sync with original AAR project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I have project-A which is a SDK and its being exported as a AAR into project-B which imports the module as a AAR how could i go about linking the two modules so changes made to the AAR in project-B don't have to be duplicated in the original project-A?

Comment: Use a maven repo instead of an aar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Project A (library), create project B(application) and put them in the same project.

update the settings.gradle file like this:

```
include ':projecta', ':projectb'
```

And make sure the projects are in the same directory

.gradle

.idea

projecta

projectb

etc

By doing this you won't have to explicitly add the aar to project B because they will be in the same project and both automatically be built when you make a release.

Edit about linking with multiple projects

In the case you want to have links to multiple projects your best bet is to create a maven repository.

Doing so will allow you to use your project in the following way:

build.gradle

```
dependencies{
    implementation com.mydomain.projecta:1.0.1
}
```

Any project you want to use you project A with can be used by writing the line above.
When you update project A you update your maven server and change the version to 1.0.2 
You also will have to update the dependencies in the linked projects:

```
dependencies{
    implementation com.mydomain.projecta:1.0.2
}
```

I think that is the most stress free way to distribute your SDK in one place and easily resuse it in multiple places.

Here are some links about setting up a maven server

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en
https://www.androidauthority.com/add-a-github-library-to-android-studio-using-maven-jcenter-jitpack-777050/

Comment: what is i make a new project named project-C that also required prohect-A?